# Java Apache POI error inserting spreadsheet Picture

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I'm trying to insert an image in a sheet using Apache POI, but I'm getting the following error:

```
    03-03 20:21:50.898: E/SELinux(28413): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload:  Error reading /seapp_contexts, line 16, name levelFrom, value container
03-03 20:21:50.908: D/dalvikvm(28413): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-03 20:21:51.668: D/libEGL(28413): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
03-03 20:21:51.678: D/libEGL(28413): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
03-03 20:21:51.708: D/libEGL(28413): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB3.04.03.00.134.050_msm8610_JB_3.2_RB3__release_AU ()
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 20.00.02
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Build Date: 11/12/13 Tue
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Local Branch: 
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Remote Branch: quic/jb_3.2_rb3.21
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Local Patches: NONE
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB3.04.03.00.134.050 +  NOTHING
03-03 20:21:51.978: D/OpenGLRenderer(28413): Enabling debug mode 0
03-03 20:21:52.518: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28413): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-03 20:21:52.528: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28413): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-03 20:21:52.538: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28413): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-03 20:21:52.538: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28413): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-03 20:21:58.468: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28413): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-03 20:21:58.468: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28413): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-03 20:21:58.978: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28413): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-03 20:21:58.978: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28413): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-03 20:22:02.368: D/dalvikvm(28413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 235K, 11% free 9609K/10696K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-03 20:22:02.418: D/dalvikvm(28413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 9% free 10061K/10972K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
03-03 20:22:02.458: D/dalvikvm(28413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 8% free 10532K/11424K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-03 20:22:02.928: D/dalvikvm(28413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 734K, 13% free 11166K/12760K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
03-03 20:22:03.398: W/dalvikvm(28413): Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/poi/ddf/DefaultEscherRecordFactory;
03-03 20:22:03.398: D/AndroidRuntime(28413): Shutting down VM
03-03 20:22:03.398: W/dalvikvm(28413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d23898)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3839)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18795)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3834)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    ... 11 more
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.AbstractEscherHolderRecord.convertToEscherRecords(AbstractEscherHolderRecord.java:78)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.AbstractEscherHolderRecord.convertRawBytesToEscherRecords(AbstractEscherHolderRecord.java:73)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.DrawingGroupRecord.processChildRecords(DrawingGroupRecord.java:79)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.findDrawingGroup(InternalWorkbook.java:2051)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.initDrawings(HSSFWorkbook.java:1588)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.addPicture(HSSFWorkbook.java:1608)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at pro.kondratev.androidreadxlsx.ReadXlsx.criar(ReadXlsx.java:136)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    ... 14 more
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: RECORD_ID
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.ddf.DefaultEscherRecordFactory.recordsToMap(DefaultEscherRecordFactory.java:135)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.ddf.DefaultEscherRecordFactory.<clinit>(DefaultEscherRecordFactory.java:42)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    ... 21 more
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: RECORD_ID
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:673)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at org.apache.poi.ddf.DefaultEscherRecordFactory.recordsToMap(DefaultEscherRecordFactory.java:129)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    ... 22 more
```

Code is:

```
public void criar (View view) throws IOException {

    String nome = ((String) txtnome.getText().toString());
    String foto = ((String) txtstring.getText().toString());

    FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("sdcard/projetos/enguelber/formulario.xls"));
    HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
    HSSFSheet sheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 

    // Nome do cliente
    Row row = sheet.getRow(7);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
    String cliente = ((String) txtcliente.getText().toString());

    cell.setCellValue(cliente); 

    // CPF do cliente
    Row row1 = sheet.getRow(7);
    Cell cell1 = row.getCell(7);
    String cpf = ((String) txtcpf.getText().toString());

        cell1.setCellValue(cpf); 

     // Hora

        String hora = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        Row row2 = sheet.getRow(35);

        Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(1);
        cell2.setCellValue(hora);

        // Foto do relatorio

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("sdcard/projetos/enguelber/fotos/02.03.2016 21.15.27.jpg");

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        int pictureIdx = my_xls_workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);

        inputStream.close();

        CreationHelper helper = my_xls_workbook.getCreationHelper();

        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setCol1(1);
        anchor.setRow1(2);

        Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

        pict.resize();

       // foto
      //  Row row3 = sheet.getRow(13);
   //     Cell cell3 = row3.getCell(1);

     //   cell3.setCellValue(foto); 

       input_document.close();
       FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("sdcard/projetos/enguelber/"+ nome + ".xls"));

        my_xls_workbook.write(output_file);

        output_file.close();

    }
```

The application works normally if I remove the lines:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("sdcard/projetos/enguelber/fotos/02.03.2016 21.15.27.jpg");

byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

int pictureIdx = my_xls_workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);

inputStream.close();


CreationHelper helper = my_xls_workbook.getCreationHelper();

Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();


ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

anchor.setCol1(1);
anchor.setRow1(2);


Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

pict.resize();
```

Stack trace: http://freetexthost.com/qakvlvuxlm

Comment: What version of POI are you running?

Comment: aa-poi-3.10-min-0.1.5.jar

Comment: Looks like you have duplicate POI jars / POI jars from different versions. [Did you try following the Apache POI FAQ on the topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)? And if not, why not, and what hapens when you do?

Comment: Basically `DefaultEscherRecordFactory` looks for a `RECORD_ID` field in a long hardcoded list of classes. If any don't have it, it will throw that error. However, as all seem to be internal, I don't see how a JAR overlap could cause this.